# Is there any way to set the Command flag in Bluetooth LE packet using Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am using ACR Reactive BluetoothLE Plugin with Xamarin.Forms. I have reversed engineered commands sent to a certain BT LE device. I am able to successfully connect and write data to the device but I am getting an error in response of the write request stating that write is not allowed from the device.  I am using the characteristic.write() method of the plugin and it sends the write with an OPCODE for Attribute Protocol of 0x12. In the packets I have decoded with working communication the OPCODE for the Attribute Protocol is 0x52 because the Command flag is set.

-Sent from Android Device Xamarin.Forms (Error response from Device)-

[image]

-Decoded Message of sniffed packet (Working Communication)-

[image]

I have not been able to find any information on setting the Command Flag in the Attribute Protocol in Android or Xamarin. Is there a way to set this flag when writing data to my BT device?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the flag was not being set was because I was issuing a characteristic.Write command. What I need to call was a characterisitc.WriteWithoutResponse() command. When you write without response it sets the Command Flag in the attribute field.